# jQuery Plugin -  Deep option modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

I am currently working a plugin with a settings variable that is fairly deep (3-4 levels in some places). Following the generally accepted jQuery Plugin pattern I have implemented a simple way for users to modify settings on the fly using the following notation:

```
$('#element').plugin('option', 'option_name', 'new_value');
```

Here is the code similar to what I am using now for the options method.

```
option: function (option, value) {
    if (typeof (option) === 'string') {
        if (value === undefined) return settings[option];

        if(typeof(value) === 'object')
            $.extend(true, settings[option], value);
        else
            settings[option] = value;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Now consider that I have a settings variable like so:

```
var settings = {
    opt: false,
    another: {
        deep: true
    }
 };
```

If I want to change the `deep` settings I have to use the following notation:

```
$('#element').plugin('option', 'another', { deep: false });
```

However, since in practice my settings can be 3-4 levels deep I feel the following notation would be more useful:

```
$('#element').plugin('option', 'another.deep', false);
```

However I'm not sure how feasible this is, nor how to go about doing it. As a first attempt I tried to "traverse" to the option in question and set it, but if I set my traversing variable it doesn't set what it references in the original settings variable.

```
option: function (option, value) {
    if (typeof (option) === 'string') {
        if (value === undefined) return settings[option];

        var levels = option.split('.'),
            opt = settings[levels[0]];
        for(var i = 1; i < levels.length; ++i)
            opt = opt[levels[i]];

        if(typeof(value) === 'object')
            $.extend(true, opt, value);
        else
            opt = value;
    }

    return this;
}
```

To say that another way: By setting `opt` after traversing, the setting it actually refers to in the `settings` variable is unchanged after this code runs.

I apologize for the long question, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

As a second attempt I can do it using `eval()` like so:

```
option: function (option, value) {
    if (typeof (option) === 'string') {
        var levels = option.split('.'),
            last = levels[levels.length - 1];

        levels.length -= 1;

        if (value === undefined) return eval('settings.' + levels.join('.'))[last];

        if(typeof(value) === 'object')
            $.extend(true, eval('settings.' + levels.join('.'))[last], value);
        else 
            eval('settings.' + levels.join('.'))[last] = value;
    }

    return this;
}
```

But I really would like to see if anyone can show me a way to *not* use eval. Since it is a user input string I would rather not run `eval()` on it because it could be anything. Or let me know if I am being paranoid, and it shouldn't cause a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're running into here comes down to the difference between variables pointing to Objects and variables for other types like Strings.  **2 variables can point to the same `Object`, but not to the same `String`**:

```
  var a = { foo: 'bar' };
  var b = 'bar';
  var a2 = a;
  var b2 = b;
  a2.foo = 'hello world';
  b2 = 'hello world';
  console.log(a.foo); // 'hello world'
  console.log(b); // 'bar'
```

Your traversal code works great until the last iteration of the loop, at which point `opt` is a variable containing the same *value* as `deep` inside the object `settings.opt.another`.  Instead, cut your loop short and use the last element of `levels` as a `key`, like

```
  var settings = {
    another: {
      deep: true
    }
  };

  var levels = 'another.deep'.split('.')
    , opt = settings;

  // leave the last element
  var i = levels.length-1;

  while(i--){
    opt = opt[levels.shift()];
  }
  // save the last element in the array and use it as a key
  var k = levels.shift();
  opt[k] = 'foobar'; // settings.another.deep is also 'foobar'
```

At this stage `opt` is a pointer to the same `Object` as `settings.another` and `k` is a `String` with the value `'deep'`

Comment: Fantastic, the confusion on references there was what was clouding the issue. Thanks for clearing that up for me; I have a working method now thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using eval rather than traversal?

```
var settings = {
opt: false,
   another: {
 deep: true,

   }
};

var x = "settings.another";
eval(x).deep = false;
alert(settings.another.deep);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using `eval` on a user input string, since using it in this manner makes my plugin accept injected javascript...

Comment: There's no security on the browser side anyway.  A user can run any js they want and send any query.

Answer (score 0):

Would the built in jQuery `$().extend()` not be exactly what you need?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

*note the second method signature with the first agument of `true` performs a deep merge...

Comment: True, but it means he would have to use the syntax he's hoping to replace here.  The goal is to access those variables with dot notation in a string argument to the function.

Comment: Like Daniel said, I am using the extend method if the user passes an object, however they HAVE to pass an object for deep settings. I'm trying to allow them the option of a string as well.